# Web View is not reloading every time in iPad web view?

Tags: ipad, ios4

First thanks in advance to have a look on my issue. My issue is my am developing webview based application. It's same like as browser but i have a issue related to reload web view. When i am getting a value form popover bookmarked and try to reload the current web view from this next bookmark url, my web view do noting. I am stuck in this issue. Although when i enter any url through it works perfectly. May i doing something wrong with web view ?

```
temp = appDeleg.strURLFromPopover;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:temp];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.myWebView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:myWebView];
```

Please have a look..

Answer (score 0):

The last line looks like very suspicious. In my experience, [self.view addSubview:myWebView] should be placed in the "initialization block" to avoid some lazy init issues. Are you sure All objects are **NOT** nil? if so, you can try to set UIWebView's delegate to your class, and  debug in each method to test if your object are properly initialized. I tried your code, work fine in my side. Below are delegate method you might consider about

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
– webViewDidStartLoad:
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

Comment: Hi i have updated it again in - webViewDidFinishLoad... but not working. But when i enter the url through textbox it works fine every time.

Comment: What you mean by "through textbox"? if you just use UIWebView, it doesn't have textbox. or you are using some framework or 3rd party code?

Comment: I mean put a text box for user interaction and the text fill by user will be responsible for webview reloading... like browser. What's u do in browsers. Just type url in textbox and press go button.

Comment: If textbox works fine but first load is not.the causes should be there are some objects are nil, or if you can see you data is loaded in - webViewDidFinishLoad. You may need to call [view setNeedsDisplay].

Comment: BTW, check out [FlatWebView](https://github.com/aaronbrethorst/FlatWebView) and [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/samvermette/SVWebViewController)